# Reverse horizontal scroll in chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, mouse, logitech-mouse, scroll-wheel

I have an issue regarding my Logitech MX Master mouse which have a dedicated horizontal scroll wheel. I've created a file in `/usr/share/x11/xorg.conf.d` called `52-mouse-map.conf` which have the following content:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "pointer:Logitech MX Master"
    Option  "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 7 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20"
EndSection
```

Whenever I boot I get the correct button mapping where 6 and 7 have swapped place to reverse horizontal direction.

```
$ xinput get-button-map 11
1 2 3 4 5 7 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

It works in my i3wm and sublime etc. but in chrome whenever I use it on websites and to scroll through tabs it is the original way which I find odd to use. "Scroll up on thump wheel scrolls to the left, and scroll down scrolls right".

Anyone who know what the reason could be why my change doesn't work for chrome but everywhere else? And maybe a fix.
Here is some info:

```
$ xinput list 11
Logitech MX Master                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 7 classes:
        Class originated from: 11. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 20
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right" "Button Side" "Button Extra" "Button Forward" "Button Back" None None None None None None None None None
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 11. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 11. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 11. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Horiz Scroll
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 11. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 3:
          Label: Rel Vert Scroll
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 11. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 2
          type: 2 (horizontal)
          increment: 15.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 11. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 3
          type: 1 (vertical)
          increment: 15.000000
          flags: 0x0
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to find any answers? This worked fine for me on 16.04 but in 18.04 chrome seems to not respect the button mapping.

Comment: @thattolleyguy really odd, It works now for me in Ubuntu 16.04 (it didn't work when I posted the question). I didn't do anything to fix it in chrome, I guess it is due to a chrome update. I'm running Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: It was working for me in 16.04 as well but when I upgraded to 18.04 it stopped working. Not sure what the difference would be.